# C# Process.HasExited always true

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Ok I made a sample website(Site.aspx) that triggers an exe. I was able to ran the exe. So the problem I'm getting is whenever I trigger the exe.. the alert message immediately pops-up bypassing proc.HasExited and proc.WaitForExit even though the process is not yet finish

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string run = @"C:\Documents and Settings\blabla\Desktop\Test\Test.exe";
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = run;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process proc;
        proc = Process.Start(start);

            while (!proc.HasExited)
            {
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();        
            Response.Write("<script>alert('done')</script>");

}
```

OK THIS IS THE EXE IM RUNNING
TEST.EXE

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i = 0;
            while (i < 5)
            {
                Console.Write("While statement ");
                // Write the index to the screen.
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                // Increment the variable.
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }


        }
```

There are no errors. I was able to run the exe by clicking the button but instead of waiting for the exe to finish the site goes straight ahead to the other codes

Comment: The fact that you've got empty catch blocks makes it very hard to diagnose what's wrong. It could be that an exception is immediately being thrown, but you're not seeing it... *Never* just swallow exceptions like this.

Comment: I tried putting exceptions before but still after clicking the button it go straight to the finally block

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by that - but I would suggest removing the try/catch/finally blocks entirely. Just let any exceptions bubble up. It'll reduce the size of your code massively, and make it a lot clearer what's going on. Your tight loop is a bad idea too - `WaitForExit` is what you want. My guess is that setup.exe is exiting quickly because you don't have appropriate privileges or something similar, but that's something different to diagnose.

Comment: My bet is that `setup.exe` opens another exe (like `msiexec.exe`) and exits. (also **never** swallow execeptions)

Comment: @JonSkeet can you give me an idea on how to use hasExited and waitForExit... I tried different solutions so that the site would wait for the exe to finish. but eventhough the exe is not yet done the site is already showing the alert message which is in the end of the code

Comment: @AhmedKraiem read my edit code tnx!

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `HasExited` at all, basically. And you're *not* currently running test.exe, you're running setup.exe which may well behave very differently.

Comment: @JonSkeet after publishing the test.cs the name became setup.exe

Comment: That sounds extremely strange - if you've created it as a console app instead of a setup application, it should just be test.exe. If you've *actually* created a setup project with some custom code, it could still be launching msiexec...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup it is strange after I publish the console application there are 3 objects created "Application Files","Setup.exe" and "test.application". The program is running with no errors but even though the exe is not yet done the site is executing the other codes which seems strange

Comment: That really doesn't sound like a normal console application project. You wouldn't normally even *have* a "publish" step for a console app. It's very unclear what you've done here, but I suggest you create a *new* console app project and see what happens.

Comment: @JonSkeet yup what im trying to do is just a sample exefile and monitor it via process.hasExited but instead of waiting for the process exit it goes straight to the other codes.. can you pls tell me the proper way to use process.hasExited?

Comment: We're getting nowhere here - I'm convinced that the reason is that you don't have a normal console app here.

Comment: @JOnSkeet well maybe can you give an example of a proper and simple exe?

Comment: Well it's not a matter of the code - it's how you've set up the project. You should just start a new project, Windows Applications, Console Application.

Comment: @JonSkeet now i pointed it on the debug project.. and it worked maybe you can put that as an answer and Ill mark it. tnx!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run an GUI app from WEB service process (IIS).  That most probably fails due to at least two restrictions:

- no gui will be ever launched from a service
- possible access right problem for file and/or folder itself.

So yes, you are correct, process is 'exited' just as it is started.

Also - waiting for something in the code that is under IIS is a bad idea.  Even with some

```
Thread.Sleep(10);
```

calls.

Comment: it should fall into a catch in that case no?

Comment: yup i agree but I just need to do it for apparent reasons.. the exe runs fore about 10 seconds but even though its not yet done the other codes from the site gets executed as well

Comment: what Im trying to accomplish is to monitor the process if its done so that I can show whats happening on the client side..

Comment: Try polling.  Create a thread that handles that, then from web page poll (jquery, former AJAX) for results of the invocation of the process.

Comment: @DanielMosmondor is there an easier way?.. what I had in mind before is while process is running it will trigger the processtemplate via proc.hasExited but is not working :(.. or maybe I can use a database that gets updated before during and after the process which i'll be reading every 5 seconds

Comment: That's pretty much the easiest way, otherwise I wouldn't recommend it.  I'm a very lazy programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation of Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0)

> In addition, Start may return a non-null Process with its HasExited property already set to true. In this case, the started process may have activated an existing instance of itself and then exited.